# Meteor: callLoginMethod not found error

Tags: meteor

I'm having difficulty invoking a login method, it follows

```
$ meteor list
Accounts-base 1.2.14 A user account system
Ecmascript 0.6.1 Compiler plugin that supports ES2015 + in all .js files
Meteor-base 1.0.4 Packages that every Meteor app needs
React 15.0.1 Everything you need to use React with Meteor.
Static-html 1.1.13 Defines static page content in .html files
```

/server/main.js

```
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base'

Accounts.registerLoginHandler('simples', (ttt) => {
  console.log(ttt);
});
```

/client/main.js

```
autenticar(){
  Accounts.callLoginMethod({
    methodName: 'simples',
    methodArguments: [{ tipo : 'simples' }],
    validateResult: function (result) {
    console.log('result', result);
    },
    userCallback: function(error) {
      if (error) {
        console.log('error', error);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

When calling authenticar(), I get this error:

```
errorClass
  Details: undefined
  Error: 404
  ErrorType: "Meteor.Error"
  Message: "Method 'simples' not found [404]"
  Reason: "Method 'simples' not found"
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used this API personally, but from a quick glance through the Meteor internals, I see a couple issues.

`Accounts.registerLoginHandler` only adds an additional handler to an array of built-in handlers which are called as part of the default Meteor login process.

If you are trying to plug in an additional handler into the existing process, you should call `Accounts.callLoginMethod` *without* the `methodName` key.

Calling `Accounts.callLoginMethod` with `methodName` will bypass the built-in handlers completely and replace them with your custom method, however this method needs to be declared separately by you with `Meteor.methods`, not `registerLoginHandler`.

So, that's probably your error -- you need to define your `simples` method with `Meteor.methods`. Also, you should check the code for the requirements of this method, see the comments in the code here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_client.js

Answer (score 1):

Only to complement and keep as a referral for someone else to get here. That way it's working

client.js

```
Accounts.callLoginMethod({
  methodArguments: [{tipo: 'simples'}],
  validateResult: (result) => {
    console.log('success', result);
  },
  userCallback: function(error) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  }
});
```

server.js

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  var config = Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.findOne({
    service : 'simples'
  });
  if (!config) {
    Accounts.loginServiceConfiguration.insert({ service: 'simples' });
  }
});

Accounts.registerLoginHandler((opts) => {
  if(opts.tipo === 'simples'){
    return Accounts.updateOrCreateUserFromExternalService ('simples', {
      id: 0 // need define something
    }, {
      options : 'optional'
    })
  }
});
```